# Debian Dual Boot. Wheezy, and Jessy

Tags: debian

Is there a way I could have a Dual Boot OS with the same OS? I want Debian, but I want Jessie, and Wheezy. Are they the same OS or are they different?

Comment: They are all Linux, yes. As long as they exist on separate partitions then there shouldn't be a problem. I'd chain load grub to point to each one so Debian Wheezy can take care of itsself and Debian Jessy can take care of itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can dual boot with the same OS, same distro, same distro version. The different partitions do not need to know about each other, although it is customary (at least when disc space was at a premium) to share swap space when dual booting.

The only thing when using the same version of a particular distro (e.g. two times Wheezy), is that it becomes less easy to keep apart the different entries in the grub startup menu.